# jQuery Form Wizard with Printable Results

Tags: jquery, forms, printing

I'd like to create a multi-step form wizard with jQuery which takes in values at each step and then is able to collect all of the inputs and present them in a printable format at the end. I can make a form wizard, I'm just not sure how to send all of the values to a printable format only using client-side code. I won't have access to any server-side stuff, so I can't handle it there. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in a jQuery plugin, I have authored one ([jWizard](https://github.com/dominicbarnes/jWizard)) that I believe can fit this situation. If you check out the "[Custom Events](http://dominicbarnes.us/jWizard/demo/events.html)" demonstration, you'll see something very similar to what you're describing.

Basically, you'll create a wizard. Then you'll bind to the `changestep` event and when you detect the user advancing to the last page of the wizard, you can intercept it and populate a "summary" panel with all the information from wizard itself. (which is exactly what I've done in the aforementioned example)

I would be more than happy to help you out with the setup, but if you're not in the market for a jQuery plugin, that's fine too.